# Show popup from another component using functions in react (.jsx)?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Hello there I'm new with Reactjs and just have a quick question.
I have a modal component that I want to show up when a function is called from another component.

1. The modal component

```
const Popup = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const toggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={toggle}>Click Me</Button>
            <Modal className='successModal text-center' open={open} centered={true} size='lg'>
                <ModalHeader>{props.title}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <div>
                        <img src={successIcon} alt='Success Icon' />
                        <div className='container my-4'>
                            <h4>{props.body}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick={toggle}>Close</Button>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Popup;
```

2. This is the function that I need to show up the popup when it's called

```
        const finishPayment = () => {
            console.log('just checking if this function is called properly');

            return (
                <Popup
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                    title='Success'
                    body='Welcome, everything was fine.'
                />
            );
        };
```

Can someone help me how to figure out this?
I think I need to pass something as props, but not sure what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are using "*onClick*" events, therefore, you must pass a *function* as argument, but you are passing a *constant*. Convert your "toggle()" *arrow function* to *function* or implement another *arrow function* inside the "*onClick*" events, so as in the examples below:

**With arrow function:**

```js
const Popup = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const toggle = () => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => toggle()}>Click Me</Button>
            <Modal className='successModal text-center' open={open} centered={true} size='lg'>
                <ModalHeader>{props.title}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <div>
                        <img src={successIcon} alt='Success Icon' />
                        <div className='container my-4'>
                            <h4>{props.body}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick={() => toggle()}>Close</Button>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Popup;
```

**With vanilla/traditional functions:**

```js
const Popup = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    function toggle() {
        setOpen(!open);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={toggle}>Click Me</Button>
            <Modal className='successModal text-center' open={open} centered={true} size='lg'>
                <ModalHeader>{props.title}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <div>
                        <img src={successIcon} alt='Success Icon' />
                        <div className='container my-4'>
                            <h4>{props.body}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick={toggle}>Close</Button>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Popup;
```